# Getting access for test account

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

Since Facebook got really strict in their policy of who can and can't access Instant Articles we're having trouble testing our app out.

I created a test user inside our app and a page for it, but applying with that page gives me the ol' This Page is ineligible for Instant Articles error.

I would have thought that access would be granted when using a test user, since none of that is visible to the public. Did anyone figure out how to setup a development account for Instant Articles? If so, how did you go about it?